# If input maxlength is reached do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, maxlength

I have a maxlength of 11 for an input field. I would like to perform a jQuery function when the maxlength has been met and the user keeps trying to type, so instead of it not doing anything, it'd show a message.

Please could you give me some pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you  may use a counter and show pop up message when counter equals maxlength

Comment: Check the `keyup` event, and within it, check the length of the input. If the condition matches, call the javascript code you want.

Comment: you can use the `keyup` or `keydown` event and check if length is the same than your max, then display your message

Answer (score 10):

Try this: IT will alert a message when the user hits 11 characters.

```
$("input").on("keyup",function() {
  var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
  if(maxLength == $(this).val().length) {
    alert("You can't write more than " + maxLength +" chacters")
  }
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("input").on("keyup",function() {
  var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
  if(maxLength == $(this).val().length) {
    alert("You can't write more than " + maxLength +" chacters")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input maxlength="11" />
```

Comment: This also triggers for keys which do not write characters, e.g. entering 11 characters and then moving the cursor using the arrow keys triggers the alert. Or when trying to copy the input using `Ctrl` +  `C`.

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#text").keypress(function(e) {
    var length = this.value.length;
    if (length >= 11) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("not allow more than 11 character");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text">
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like:

```
$("input").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.target.value.length==11){
        alert("maxlength reached");
    }
});
```

Obviously change to use the correct selector and alert/modal popup.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").keyup(function(){
var a = $(this).val().length;
if(a >= 11){
$(this).attr('maxlength','11')
alert("not allowed")
}
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the $(document) it will find all the inputs with maxlength attribute, even if you have created them after loading the page.

```js
$(document).on("input keypress", "input[maxlength]", function (e) {
    var $input = $(e.currentTarget);
    if ($input.val().length >= $input.attr("maxlength")) {
        alert("Max length reached")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<input>
```